# Limit transformation levels from int to factor

Tags: r, integer, categories

I have a int column with int values. I would like to transform it to factor with predefined number of buckets/ levels/ sub ranges.
Here is an example:

```
dat1 <- fread('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/haberman/haberman.data',stringsAsFactors=T)
dat1 <- data.frame(lapply(dat1, as.factor))
> str (dat1)
'data.frame':   306 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ V1: Factor w/ 49 levels "30","31","33",..: 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ V2: Factor w/ 12 levels "58","59","60",..: 7 5 8 2 8 1 3 2 9 1 ...
 $ V3: Factor w/ 31 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 2 4 1 3 5 11 1 1 10 28 ...
 $ V4: Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 ...
```

I would like to divide the source `dat1$V3` lets say to ranges (each one is level). Each of the source values will fall of one of these categories.

Comment: You want `?cut`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use -

```
dat1$V3_cut <- cut(as.numeric(dat1$V3), 5)
```

**Output**

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4   V3_cut
1 30 64  1  1 (0.97,7]
2 30 62  3  1 (0.97,7]
3 30 65  0  1 (0.97,7]
4 31 59  2  1 (0.97,7]
5 31 65  4  1 (0.97,7]
6 33 58 10  1   (7,13]
```

**or**

```
dat1$V3_cut <- cut(as.numeric(dat1$V3), c(0,3,5,11))
```

**Output**

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V3_cut
1 30 64  1  1  (0,3]
2 30 62  3  1  (3,5]
3 30 65  0  1  (0,3]
4 31 59  2  1  (0,3]
5 31 65  4  1  (3,5]
6 33 58 10  1 (5,11]
```

You can either specify the number of `cut` or provide a list consisting of the class boundaries. By default `include.lowest` is `FALSE` which is signified by `(]` of the boundaries

**EDIT**
Thanks @Rui -

```
dat1$V3_cut <- cut(as.numeric(dat1$V3), c(0,3,5,11), labels=1:3)
```

Comment: I would like to add levels (dat1$V3) = c(1:4). Is there a way to it in one command?

Comment: @Avi You can set argument `labels = 1:4`

Comment: @RuiBarradas valuable suggestion! Edited ans :)